# Jmeter 3.0 Dashboard graph not match with listener graph

Tags: jmeter

am using thread group and stepping thread group.

running jmeter from command line and generate .jtl file with csv format.
then generate report using -o command line options.

The problem for some graph output are different compare to graph output in listener UI

e.g
**Response Times Over Time**

graph from listener when i load from .jtl file
[image: graph from listener when i load from .jtl file]

graph from dashboard
[image: graph from dashboard]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Granularity of JMeter-Plugins graph seems to be different from the JMeter core one.

You can try different settings by changing in user.properties:

> jmeter.reportgenerator.overall_granularity=60000

Comment: Thanks. What is the recommended value for granularity in user.properties and listener?

Comment: Hello, no recommendation, it depends on your test case, the detail you want, the duration of test ...